# React Navigation 5, get closest parent navigator name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Imagine you have this navigation system:

```
  -TabNavigator
      --TabA
          ---StackNavigatorA
             ----ScreenA
             ----StackNavigatorB
      --TabB
          ---StackNavigatorB
             ----ScreenB
```

Is there any way, using React Navigation 5, to get the closest parent navigator name? For example, if I am in the screen "ScreenA" and execute the method I need, this will return "StackNavigatorA"

Something like this:

```
     const currentNavigator = navigation.getCurrentNavigator(); // <--- getCurrentNavigator doesn't exist, this is pseudocode.
     console.log(currentNavigator); // Will show the closest parent navigator
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get closest navigation parent you can use [dangerouslyGetParent()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dangerouslygetparent) from navigation prop.

Also, "This method will return undefined if there is no parent navigator. Be sure to always check for undefined when using this method."

To check if navigator is its parents, you can define a custom key to each navigator to do your validations when necessary.

Comment: Does it provides the navigator name? I can only see its key (which is random).

Comment: You can provide your navigation key using key prop in Navigator.

Comment: Not working. I do <Stack.Navigator key="ProfileStack" ... /> and when I do console.log(navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state) I see the key is: "stack-Icyp6Vv45Kq_7D5G6if7L"